# Why Area give the wrong results when the region cannot be formed?

Tags: functions, bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 11.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.2.0 or later**

---

I use `Area` function to evaluate the area of the polygon. I found that when two vertex points are the same, the `Area` give the wrong result. For example, I define the following function:

```
areacoor[x_, y_] := Area@Polygon[{{x, y}, {0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}}]
```

which is the area of the triangle whose vertex points is {x, y}, {0.5, 0.5} and {1, 1}. When $(x,y)$ move towards to any two other points, for example, $(x,y)\to (0.5,0.5)$, the area of the  triangle will become smaller and smaller. When $(x,y)=(0.5,0.5)$, the triangle will become a line and the area should be 0. However `areacoor[0.5,0.5]` gives 0.707107. I wonder why I obtain this result, which I think is not reasonable.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Maybe somebody tried to make the definition of `Area` rebust for degenerating polygons, deleted duplicate vertex coordinates and somewhat mixed up `Area` and `RegionMeasure`...

Comment: Added the bugs tag. Please report it to the tech support.

Comment: `Area[Polygon[{{0.4`, 0.4`}, {0.5`, 0.5`}, {1, 1}}]]`, too, misfires.

Comment: in 11.1 other colinear point sets generate an (incomprehensible) error message.  Only a "wrong" result for coincident points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question! Workaround with Evaluate works as expected:

```
areacoor[x_ , y_ ] :=Evaluate@Area@Polygon[{{x, y}, {0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}}]     
areacoor[0.5, 0.5 ] 
(* 0 *)
Plot3D [areacoor[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**appendix**
Without Evaluate the bug(comment @Henrik Schumacher) can be illustrated

```
Plot3D [Area[Polygon[{{x, y}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}}] ], {x, 0, 1}, {y,0, 1}]
```

[image]